Did The Binding of Isaac have religious backlash?
When Cult of the Lamb first released, some people took to the internet and warned people not to play it because they thought it would turn people toward the devil’s side (or similar blasphemous ideas).
Given The Binding of Isaac’s content, I was wondering if anything similar happened (for any of the games in the series).

Since you tagged both BoI and CotL I feel this can be a "too broad" question. Btw of course Isaac has religious backlash, it's strongly inspired by biblical (and other religions) elements, but people only consider the "pacts with the devil" mechanic. It's a bit blasphemous, but it's just a game.

@pinckerman I mostly tagged CotL because it was somewhat related. I can remove it. And I knew that it probably had backlash, I just wanted to know how.

And I know it's just a game (so is CotL), but some people would probably still get angry over it. Mostly just a curiosity question.

Yeah but I don't think this can be answered, people get angry with everything, Pokemon for example still has a plethora of haters despite an official blessing...

@pinckerman If people  can get angry with anything, then an answer saying that people got angry and how would answer the question. I'd probably mark it as accepted if it was suitable.

I think you should define "backlash". Or are you asking if people were actually, literally afraid it would turn BoI players into satanists (which seems like a ridiculous claim, on par with how playing violent video games turns boys into school shooters &c.)?

@Joachim I want to know if people actually thought BoI would turn people into satanists, like how some people thought CotL would.

There was some backlash, but nothing to the extent that could be witnessed by CotL.
This article from 2015 suggests the game needs a "defence" by an ex-fundamentalist christian, but the defence is against allegations that the game is anti-christian in an /r/atheism way, rather than anti-chistian in an "convert your children to satanism" way. The article really doesn't seem to point at a supposedly massive wave of attacks or backlash against the game, simply that it has some detractors.
This GeeksUnderGrace article from 2016 is an attack on the game for its blasphemous themes, and it also attacks McMillen directly for renouncing (or at least, sort of) his faith. Crucially, it itself observes that there hadn't been much backlash against the game, and cites an interview where McMillen states that such backlash may bring more publicity to the game, and that it hadn't happened yet.
Outside the internet, there probably were some very angry people saying very angry things, but it was not to an extent sufficient to reach mainstream nor gaming news publications to immortalize it.
